# attach vscode debugger to a pip installed .whl within a running docker image?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, pip

I build my python project (fastapi) with poetry and in the build docker stage i install copy and install the newly build wheel.

my dev environment works but i get a diferent (erronious) behviour when running the API in the docker image. (may be due mount / network issues) but its dificult to understand the circumstances without being able to set breakpoints.

i have tried to run it (docker-compose) and included this statement in the sourcecode build.

```
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
debugpy.wait_for_client()
```

The program seems to wait:

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container service_manager_docker_test  Created                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
Attaching to service_manager_docker_test
service_manager_docker_test  | 0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
service_manager_docker_test  | 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
service_manager_docker_test  | 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
service_manager_docker_test  | 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

then I try to attach to it via vscode:

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
```

it seems to attach and then just run without reacting to my breakoints. and right now i am assuming that is because I am running the pip installed version of the wheel on files within the pithon package library and not on my sourcecode folder.
As i am planing to release the image using the pip install method i would like to be able to debug the code exactly as it will run in production.

Does anyone have any hints for this?
or any good resources for debugging python within dockercontainers using vs code. i've watched quite few videos but they all seem to do things diferently and i cannot find a good best practice tutorial / documentation for my situation.

Comment: Setting `"justMyCode": false` should allow you to set breakpoints in installed packages.